# Finding multicolour blobs opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to detect a big yellow object having an orange centre. Unfortunately, there are other yellow objects in the scene, also other orange ones. The biggest, irritating yellow object which is not the correct one has a bright grey centre as well. So I try to find a yellow blop /contour, where there is orange in the near, but no big grey part.

I do have three arrays called maskRGB[Yellow, Grey, Orange] with Booleans being True or False it its orange, yellow or grey in those pixels.

My current code for the contours and the blob looks like that, but that is only checking the yellow part. Is there any good way to combine those? I am talking in particular about blobs with colours bordering each other.

```
contoursYellow = cv2.findContours(maskRGBYellow.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
blob = max(contoursYellow, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

Is there a good solution for that?

Edit: Added an example image
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including some exemplary input image.

Comment: Please post the image.

Comment: @AnnZen I have added an image. Actually, the objects are moving, but thats a further problem I would like to look in deeper later :)

Comment: @HansHirse Its a huge programme and I will try to filter out the relevant parts